# coordinates mouse canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent, onmouseover

So ... I created canvas element with jquery:

```
var canvasElement = $("<canvas id='map' width='" + CANVAS_WIDTH + "' height='" + CANVAS_HEIGHT + "'></canvas");
var canvas = canvasElement.get(0).getContext("2d");
canvasElement.appendTo('body');
```

And now i want to get mouse coordinates, but the next code doesn't work:

```
canvasElement.onmousemove = mousemove;
function mousemove(evt) {
  var mouseX = evt.pageX - canvasElement.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = evt.pageY - canvasElement.offsetTop;
  alert(mouseX+":"+mouseY);
}
```

canvasElement.offsetLeft is not work, evt.pageX too... Help !

Comment: Do you have to define function mousemove() before you try and call it?

Comment: That's irrelevant at runtime. Function declarations are hoisted up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those properties aren't cross-browser.

I know of two solutions to get the canvas position :

- the easy one : use [jQuery offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)
- another one : use a custom and complex code :

  ```
   if (!canvasElement.offsetX) {
      // firefox
      var obj = canvasElement;
      var oX = obj.offsetLeft;var oY = obj.offsetTop;
      while(obj.parentNode){
          oX=oX+obj.parentNode.offsetLeft;
          oY=oY+obj.parentNode.offsetTop;
          if(obj==document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]){break}
          else{obj=obj.parentNode;}
      }
      canvas_position_x = oX;
      canvas_position_y = oY;
  } else {
      // chrome
      canvas_position_x = canvasElement.offsetX;
      canvas_position_y = canvasElement.offsetY;
  }
  ```

As there is a loop, you'd better store `canvas_position_x` and `canvas_position_y` and have them recomputed at each document `resize` instead of at each `mousemove`.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/CrvgB/)

Comment: guys how you so fast answer in my questions?:D thx, i try this method tommorow

Comment: I copy pasted from one of my old programs.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, I'd recommend to use it, not because the other solution is bad but to have a cleaner and lighter code.

Comment: This doesn't work. Also recommending using jQuery for anything canvas related is a terrible idea. Including over 2k lines of code just to get the mouse coords (which is quite easy in JS) is pretty bad advice.

Comment: @dystroy thats not my intention. I rarely down vote. This flat out doesn't work though (the code you posted), thats the reason for the down vote.

Comment: ah, you're just getting the top and left, the OP wants the mouse coordinates (at least that is my assumption) within the canvas where clicked. I think thats where the confusion lies. Ill remove the downvote as it does work for what you're doing :P

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/3AdAk/)**

Its pretty easy actually without jQuery. Below is the important part from the fiddle. `cX` and `cY` are the coordinates of the clicked canvas.

```
function clicked(e) {
    var cX = 0,
        cY = 0;

    if (event.pageX || event.pageY) {
        cX = event.pageX;
        cY = event.pageY;
    }
    else {
        cX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        cY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    cX -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    cY -= canvas.offsetTop;

    ctx.fillRect(cX, cY, 2, 2);

}​
```

**[Demo with mouse move](http://jsfiddle.net/3AdAk/2/)**

Comment: @user1786016 applying it to the mouse move works the same. I just added another demo link with mouse move.